# Zurb Foundation 4, Off Canvas and Shopify

Tags: zurb-foundation, shopify, liquid

Hi I am trying to get zurb foundation 4 to have the off canvas mobile menu work within my shopify store. the issue I am having is that it is displaying the menu button fine, but it isn't triggering anything when clicked and the preloaded sidebar is visable on desktop

the code i have used so far is

```
<!-- mobile only side bar -->
    <header class="row">
        <div class="large-8 columns small-2">
            <p class="show-for-small">
              <a class='sidebar-button button' id="sidebarButton" href="#sidebar" >Menu</a>
            </p>
      </div>
        <section id="sidebar" role="complementary">
            <nav id="sideMenu" role="navigation">
                <ul id="sideMainNav" class="nav-bar">
                    <li><a href="">test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Four</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
        </header>
    <!-- /mobile -->


<!-- Check for Zepto support, load jQuery if necessary -->
<script>
  document.write('<script src=/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>   

{{ 'zepto.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
{{ 'foundation.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
{{ 'jquery.offcanvas.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Comment: Do you have `<body class="off-canvas hide-extras">` already?

Comment: no i don't ill add it see what happens. thanks

Comment: that fixed the menu being visible on desktop, yet i still cant work out why the onclick isn being triggered

Comment: make sure it is loading your JS. Put some `console.log` statements in offcanvas.js to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Oh, remove this line `{{ 'zepto.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}` you are loading zepto twice.

Comment: could it be that offcanvas needs jquery and im using zepto from foundation 4?

Comment: this code: 
`<script>
  document.write('<script src=/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>   `

Loads Zepto (jquery compatible library). When zepto is not supported (IE) it loads jquery.

Just as a troubleshooting step I would try removing

`<script>
  document.write('<script src=/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>   ` and `{{ 'zepto.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}`

and import jquery perhaps with `{{ 'jquery.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}`

Comment: using jquery.js fixed the issue weird

Comment: I just took a peek at `offcanvas.js`. It's not that weird since it calls a couple methods not available in zepto. It calls `scrollTop` for instance.

Comment: @AustinPray if you wanted to put your comment as answer will accept it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `<body class="off-canvas hide-extras">` already?

this code: `<script> document.write('<script src=/' + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') + '.js><\/script>'); </script>` Loads Zepto (jquery compatible library). When zepto is not supported (IE) it loads jquery. Just as a troubleshooting step I would try removing `<script> document.write('<script src=/' + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') + '.js><\/script>'); </script>` and `{{ 'zepto.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}` and import jquery perhaps with `{{ 'jquery.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}`

I just took a peek at offcanvas.js. It's not that weird since it calls a couple methods not available in zepto. It calls scrollTop for instance. Use jQuery and it will work fine.